# api script for multi account adder telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Hi I'm working on a multi add telegram member and here is the code:

```
ffrom telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
import csv

    api_id = 5961821  #Enter Your 7 Digit Telegram API ID.
    api_hash = 'bcc6ac1940207e2c7c460413b90efdaa'   #Enter Yor 32 Character API Hash.
    phone = '21695953978'   #Enter Your Mobilr Number With Country Code.
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
    async def main():
        # Now you can use all client methods listed below, like for example...
        await client.send_message('me', 'Hello !!!!')
    with client:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
    client.connect()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        client.send_code_request(phone)
        client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter verification code: '))
    
    
    chats = []
    last_date = None
    chunk_size = 200
    groups=[]
    
    result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
                 offset_date=last_date,
                 offset_id=0,
                 offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
                 limit=chunk_size,
                 hash = 0
             ))
    chats.extend(result.chats)
    
    for chat in chats:
        try:
            if chat.megagroup== True:
                groups.append(chat)
        except:
            continue
    
    print('From Which Group Yow Want To Scrape Members:')
    i=0
    for g in groups:
        print(str(i) + '- ' + g.title)
        i+=1
    
    g_index = input("Please! Enter a Number: ")
    target_group=groups[int(g_index)]
    
    print('Fetching Members...')
    all_participants = []
    all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)
    
    print('Saving In file...')
    with open("Scraped.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:#Enter your file name.
        writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
        writer.writerow(['username','user id', 'access hash','name','group', 'group id'])
        for user in all_participants:
            if user.username:
                username= user.username
            else:
                username= ""
            if user.first_name:
                first_name= user.first_name
            else:
                first_name= ""
            if user.last_name:
                last_name= user.last_name
            else:
                last_name= ""
            name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
            writer.writerow([username,user.id,user.access_hash,name,target_group.title, target_group.id])
    print('Members scraped successfully.......')
```

How I can do to be able to add several API with several phone number? My goal is to be able to access several API files at the same time and use them instead of just one like in this script.

I want to have access to several phone numbers instead of just one like in this script. The script uses the first one then adds the second and the third...
I want to access several accounts at the same time to avoid the flood error and the restriction of adding 50 members per day.

Great thanks!

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ and __scraped__ not scrap or scrapped

Comment: ok thx 
any  suggestion?

Comment: any one have solution